# Draw camera aligned quad at correct world position?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am having trouble drawing a quad facing a fixed (but rotated) orthographic camera. The orthographic camera is displaying a 3D world in a isometric projection. Now I need to place isomertic sprites in the world so these quads eventually need to be displayed in the correct world position. But currently I'm trying to just draw one at the center of the world.

```
// FloorObject just holds the UV coordinates to be used.
public void addBillboard(FloorObject floorObject) {
    Vector3 direction =  new Vector3(1, 0, 0).nor();
    Vector3 cameraDirection = cam.direction;//cam.position.cpy().sub(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)).nor();

    Vector3 leftRight = direction;

    float dot = direction.cpy().dot(cameraDirection);

    cam.normalizeUp();
    Vector3 updown = cam.up;//new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

    if (Math.abs(dot) < 1f) {
        updown = direction.cpy().crs(cameraDirection);
    }
    updown.nor();

    Vector3 position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    Vector3 bottomLeft = position.cpy().add(updown).sub(leftRight);
    Vector3 topLeft = position.cpy().sub(updown).sub(leftRight);
    Vector3 bottomRight = position.cpy().add(updown).add(leftRight);
    Vector3 topRight = position.cpy().sub(updown).add(leftRight);

    // Adding verts to the buffer.

    // Bottom left
    verts[vi++] = bottomLeft.x;
    verts[vi++] = bottomLeft.y;
    verts[vi++] = bottomLeft.z;
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getU();
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getV2();
    verts[vi++] = 1;

    // Bottom right
    verts[vi++] = bottomRight.x;
    verts[vi++] = bottomRight.y;
    verts[vi++] = bottomRight.z;
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getU2();
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getV2();
    verts[vi++] = 1;

    // Top left
    verts[vi++] = topLeft.x;
    verts[vi++] = topLeft.y;
    verts[vi++] = topLeft.z;
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getU();
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getV();
    verts[vi++] = 1;

    // Top right
    verts[vi++] = topRight.x;
    verts[vi++] = topRight.y;
    verts[vi++] = topRight.z;
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getU2();
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getV();
    verts[vi++] = 1;

}
```

Using this with my isometric projection the quad is rotated about 27.5 degrees. When using a perspective camera it is rotating all over the place. I really only care to get a isometric texture getting displayed at the correct world position using that isometric camera.

In case it matters, I need to be drawing these sprites in a specific order depending on the other geometry in the scene. So I call this method in order (back to front) whenever I need to draw a isometric sprite and it gets added to the VertexBuffer in the correct order.

Comment: Replace `Vector3 leftRight = direction;` with `Vector3 leftRight = cam.up.cpy().crs(cam.direction).scl(-1);`. I think (didn't test). BTW, you don't need to copy a vector before doing a dot product on it (that doesn't affect it). If you are running this method for all your sprites, you probably want to have a reusable vector on hand rather than all these allocations from using `cpy()`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks, will try this to see the result but I actually got a much simpler (or at least shorter) piece of code that works. Will post later.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a very short (in code) solution. Involving the view matrix of the camera, I do not have thorough understanding on matrices but they essentially contain the rotation, scale and transformation. So in my last example I created 2 vectors "leftRight" and "upDown" and I renamed these to just "right" and "up" representing the camera right and up direction in the world view, often called model view as well. This is how I got the correct values from the camera's view matrix.

```
    right.x = modelview.val[0];
    right.y = modelview.val[4];
    right.z = modelview.val[8];

    up.x = modelview.val[1];
    up.y = modelview.val[5];
    up.z = modelview.val[9];
```

It just looks up the values in the array. I tried this very earlier but used incorrect lookup indices. Having these, the math to transform a vertex is pretty straightforward.

```
    float size = 1.4142135624f;

    Vector3 bottomLeft = position.cpy().sub(right.cpy().scl(size * .5f));
    Vector3 bottomRight = position.cpy().add(right.cpy().scl(size * .5f));
    Vector3 topRight = position.cpy().add(right.cpy().scl(size * .5f)).add(up.cpy().scl(size * 2));
    Vector3 topLeft = position.cpy().sub(right.cpy().scl(size * .5f)).add(up.cpy().scl(size * 2));
```

Since my floor quads are of size 1x1 I need to do Pythagoras `1.414..` since it needs to fill up a complete tile. Then I calculate the position of each vertex, since I needed to place the bottom center of the quad in a exact world position I multiply the size by `.5` and my billboards need to be double the size in height so I multiply the size with the up vector by 2. To make this faster, create 2 constants (width and height) for this so the multiplications won't be necessary. Then when these are calculated I can just batch my vertices like usual.

```
    // Bottom left
    verts[vi++] = bottomLeft.x;
    verts[vi++] = bottomLeft.y;
    verts[vi++] = bottomLeft.z;
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getU();
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getV2();
    verts[vi++] = 1;

    // Bottom right halfway
    verts[vi++] = bottomRight.x;
    verts[vi++] = bottomRight.y;
    verts[vi++] = bottomRight.z;
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getU2();
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getV2();
    verts[vi++] = 1;

    // Top left
    verts[vi++] = topLeft.x;
    verts[vi++] = topLeft.y;
    verts[vi++] = topLeft.z;
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getU();
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getV();
    verts[vi++] = 1;

    // Top right halway
    verts[vi++] = topRight.x;
    verts[vi++] = topRight.y;
    verts[vi++] = topRight.z;
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getU2();
    verts[vi++] = floorObject.getV();
    verts[vi++] = 1;
```